# Flask SQLAlchemy querying a column with "not equals"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I can query my `Seat` table for all seats where there is no invite assigned:

```
seats = Seat.query.filter_by(invite=None).all()
```

However, when querying for all seats that have an invite assigned, I get a `NameError`:

```
seats = Seat.query.filter_by(invite!=None).all()
```

```
NameError: name 'invite' is not defined
```

Here is my `Seat` class:

```
class Seat(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    invite_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('invite.id'))
    invite = db.relationship('Invite',
        backref=db.backref('folks', lazy='dynamic'))
```

How can I query for all seats where the owner is not blank?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

The [`filter_by()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by) method takes a sequence of keyword arguments, so you always have to use `=` with it.

You want to use the [`filter()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter) method which allows for `!=`:

```
seats = Seat.query.filter(Seat.invite != None).all()
```

Answer (score 56):

I think this can help
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.isnot

## Is None

```
query.filter(User.name == None)
```

or alternatively, if pep8/linters are a concern
    `query.filter(User.name.is_(None))`

## Is not None

```
query.filter(User.name != None)
```

or alternatively, if pep8/linters are a concern

`query.filter(User.name.isnot(None))`

Comment: You can also use #  NOQA

Comment: I am trying to filter out none values out of a label field, it does not seem to work: `q = session.query(Table1.id, (Table2.column1 + Table2.column2).label('table2_sum')).filter(q.c.table2_sum!=None)` Gives me q used before declaration error and `q = q.filter(q.c.table2_sum!=None)` gives me "query object has no attribute  c error"...

Comment: you must define q before to use it. Try

` q = session.query(Table1.id, (Table2.column1 + Table2.column2).label('table2_sum'))  
q = q.filter((Table2.column1 + Table2.column2)!=None) `
and let me know

Comment: pep8 concerns perfect

Comment: This one is better, also fixes pep8