# How to use filter_by and not equals to in sqlalchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy, sqlanywhere

I have a function defined as below to query the database table

```
def query_from_DB(obj, **filter):

    DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = DBSession()

    res = session.query(obj).filter_by(**filter)
    session.close()

    return [x for x in res]
```

I query the table using the request as below

```
query_from_DB(Router, sp_id="sp-10.1.10.149", connectivity="NO")
```

the above result returns the response from the DB correctly, but when I make a query using

```
query_from_DB(Router, sp_id!="sp-10.1.10.149", connectivity="NO")
```

i got an error

```
 SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

What could be the possible changes I can make to get the result?

Comment: Creating a `sessionmaker` instance every time you make a query is an anti-pattern. You can move the line `DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)` outside of `query_from_DB`. See [When Do I Make a sessionmaker](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-make-a-sessionmaker). Also closing your session before using the objects returned from the query can create issues if you haven't eager loaded any relationships.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can use `!=` on a keyword argument.

You can do `connectivity="YES"` or use the `filter` sqlalchemy function so you can pass `==` or `!=`, but then you won't be able to use keyword args. You'd have to pass a SQL expression like so...
`res = session.query(obj).filter_by(connectivity != "NO")`

This question may be helpful...
[flask sqlalchemy querying a column with not equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093475/flask-sqlalchemy-querying-a-column-with-not-equals?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score -3):

Did you simply try `res = session.query(obj).filter_by(connectivity <> "NO")` ?